# How can i add a variable to the html in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Here is my jquery i need to add the my_var inside the text

```
var my_var = <?php echo($my_var); ?>;
$("#dialog-confirms").html("Your code is myvar, Are you sure to Submit this Form ?");
```

How can i add the `my_var` inside the HTML of the `#dialog-confirms`

So the output should be

> Your code is 51, Are you sure to Submit this Form ?

Answer (score 3):

Use this

```
var my_var = "<?php echo $my_var; ?>";

$("#dialog-confirms").html("Your code is" + myvar + ", Are you sure to Submit this Form?");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a variable inside your html. Just add before and after your variable.

So, you shold have

```
$("#dialog-confirms").html("Your code is "+my_var+", Are you sure to Submit this Form ?");
```

Comment: And what would be the link between your example and ` append`?

Comment: Ah, sorry i mean to say just add the `+`

Answer (score 1):

You should use Sulthan's answer, but in the future you will be able to use JavaScript's new [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings).  It's already available in Chrome and FireFox:

```
$("#dialog-confirms").html(`Your code is ${myvar}, Are you sure to Submit this Form ?`);
```

Comment: Yes, `${value}`  shall be used while we consider about future :)

Answer (score 0):

Hey You can do this by changing your jquery code as shown below:

```
$("#dialog-confirms").html(**"Your code is"+my_var+"**, Are you sure to Submit this Form ?");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var my_var = <?php echo($my_var); ?>;
$("#dialog-confirms").html("Your code is "+myvar+", Are you sure to Submit this Form ?");
```

Use the + sign in javascript to append variables to string